# Local image and css not working in wkwebview ios 11

Tags: css, ios, objective-c, wkwebview, xcode11

Local image and CSS working fine in `UIWebview`, but after converting `UIWebView` to `WkWebView`, a local image is not loading on the webpage. In the simulator, an image is loading but in the real device, it is not loading.

```
[bookView loadHTMLString:displayStr baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:chapterPath]];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXP9I.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The question as posed currently is not comprehensible unless you add more details. Please follow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Please provide code and screenshots of output if that is possible